# My DAX query is working in Direct Query mode but not in import mode

Tags: powerbi, dax

I Have the below query to get the Avg days to solve error by users. This query is working in Direct Query mode but its not working in Import mode. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

AvgErrorFixDays = AVERAGEX(
FILTER(
New_Errors,
New_Errors[fix_date] <> "NULL"
&& New_Errors[error_date] <> "NULL"
),
DATEDIFF(New_Errors[error_date], New_Errors[fix_date], DAY)
)

Answer (score 0):

Replace "NULL" with Blank()

```
AvgErrorFixDays = AVERAGEX( FILTER( New_Errors, New_Errors[fix_date] <> Blank() && New_Errors[error_date] <> Blank() ), DATEDIFF(New_Errors[error_date], New_Errors[fix_date], DAY) )
```

Comment: Hello Ashok, Thank you for replying to my query. I am still facing this issue. This modified query also is not working in port mode. I am getting the error message:  MdxScript(Model) (5, 34) Calculation error in measure 'New_Errors'[AvgErrorFixDays]: Cannot convert value 'NULL' of type Text to type Date.

Comment: When I used Blank() in place of "NULL", it worked for me